# monkey patch not working? (using it to change a function of a class in external library)

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I'm trying to change an external library's function (inside of a class). My objective is to, while I execute my python program, change some lines inside that function. I've seen some examples and I think I'm doing it correctly, but maybe there is some nuances I don't fully understand that makes the code not to work. My python main program is in home directory and I'm using tianshou as an external library installed via pip inside a conda environment.

My main program (`~/projects/testing_ground/main.py`) is something like this:

```
import testing_ground.monkey
from tianshou.data import Collector
from tianshou.env import DummyVectorEnv
from tianshou.utils import TensorboardLogger

def auxiliar_func():
    #do_something
def main_func():
    #do_main_thing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    auxiliar_func()
    main_func()
```

`main_func` is the main function that calls to the class `OffpolicyTrainer` inside `tianshou` external library. That class is the child of the `BaseTrainer` class that has the function `test_step`, the one I want to change. The path of the both `test_step` function and `BaseTrainer` class are in `tianshou.trainer.utils`. As I've seen in recommendations, I added the `monkey` python file as import before the main `tianshou` libraries.

This is the monkey patch file's content (`~/projects/testing_ground/monkey.py`):

```
import tianshou.trainer.utils
def my_test_episode(*args, **kwargs):
    result = tianshou.trainer.utils.test_episode(*args, **kwargs)
    print("check comment in execution to know it works")
    return result
setattr(tianshou.trainer.utils, 'test_episode', my_test_episode)
```

I also tested this other monkey patch (same file with other content):

```
import tianshou.trainer.utils
def my_test_episode(*args, **kwargs):
    result = tianshou.trainer.utils.test_episode(*args, **kwargs)
    print("check comment in execution to know it works")
    return result
tianshou.trainer.utils.test_episode = my_test_episode
```

But I can't seem to make it work and show the `print`. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to patch anything? Can't you just _extend_ the class you're using whose behaviour you want to change?

Comment: It is not easier with monkey patch? If I could do what you say inside `main.py` without repeating all the code of the external library it could be the best solution. Although I'm not sure how to change a parent class' function without repeating a lot whole of code.

Comment: Also, there are multiple calls from inside the external library to that function. Those also must be changed. Could that also work if I change the function only in my `main.py` via inheritance?

Comment: @AurelieNavir I'm not familiar with this library, but I think monkeypatching doesn't persist in child Python processes. If the library you are using is doing some multiprocessing, the monkeypatch may not be applied in the process that attempts to run `tianshou.trainer.utils.test_episode`.

Comment: That definitely could be the problem because I know that the library uses multiprocessing and when executing my code it spans a lot of other processes. In that case, what could be the best way to achieve what I want? Maybe change directly the library's code and comment it when I don't need it? Or make a local copy of the library, change it and import it for when I want to use it like that?

Comment: If you only need to make the change temporarily, changing the code directly sounds like a reasonable option; I sometimes do that for the sake of debugging. If you're going to be distributing your code and need this change, you might make a local copy or look into what johnrsharpe suggested.